# Coded UI Tests aren't doing anything

Tags: coded-ui-tests

This is my first look at Coded UI tests. I've hand coded a test that successfully opens the a browser window to my local web project, but then it just sits there and does nothing. I've tried clicking a hyperlink and putting text in a textbox.

I've set a break point and stepped through the code, but nothing ever happens on the page. I'm clearly missing something.

Comment: Okay, more information. It isn't doing nothing. It is just running unbelievably slow. Is that because it's running against localhost? Suggestions?

Comment: It will run faster if you are not debugging the site you are testing (no idea why that is).  If you deploy the site and test it that way, then it will be much faster.  Also, depending on what you are doing in the tests, there are built in delays to help give time for things to settle down, you may be running into those problems as well.  if you can post some of the code, it would help identify any issues like that.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that it just runs really slow.

Comment: I can see that, 6 days to run the test! :P